# Eclipse TreeViewer - First column contents not getting aligned

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have an eclipse application wherein I am using a TreeViewer. 
There are three columns in the TreeViewer.
On click of a button, I have to align the contents of the all the columns to either right or left.

I tried the following, but I do not see any changes to the FIRST column on the TreeViewer. 
The contents of the first column seem to be always left aligned.

```
rightAlignButton.addListener(SWT.MouseDoubleClick, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        TreeColumn[] connectionViewerColumns = connectionViewer.getTree().getColumns();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < connectionViewerColumns.length ; i++){
            connectionViewerColumns[i].setAlignment(SWT.RIGHT);
        }
    }
});
```

Could anyone please let me how it is done, what is my mistake here? It would be very helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc for `TreeColumn.setAlignment` says:

> Note that due to a restriction on some platforms, the first column is
>   always left aligned.